# How to manage ASP.NET Identity Users with Roles and OOP inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am coming up with classes for a web app to handle a payment gateway.  The application is going to be a ASP.NET web app using Identity 2.0 to handle and manage users.  I will have 4 different types/roles of users that will sign into the application.

Example of different users

1. Customers
2. Contractors
3. SubContractors
4. Employees

Some of these user classes have additional data to be store than other users. I am trying to figure out how to handle this.

Example: A customer will have a specified Contractor they use.  No other users (Subcontractor, Contractor, and Employee) will not have this property.

I am wonder if I can use the out of the box identity `rolemanager` to handle these different roles or if I should use inheritance from the default `appliationsuser` class and make 4 different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using ASP.NET Identity then I will do something like this:

- Insert the following role names in `IdentityRole` table: `Customers`, `Contractors`, `SubContractors` and `Employees`. Or only just for those who will use your application.
- Create new classes : `Customer`, `Contractor`, `SubContractor` and `Employee`. These classes should derived from `IdentityUser` class.
- Every specific property should be defined into the associated derived class. So because a customer will have a specified `Contractor` they use then you create a property of type `Contractor` in `Customer` class.
- The only thing to take care here is when you're creating an instance that is derived from `User`, make sure you add the correct role to it.

Comment: Do I have to do anything special now that I will have 4 seperate classes instead of 1 ApplicationUser Classes?

Comment: You can use one class ApplicationUser but you will end up with all specific properties into the same classe. So it will end up that some developers on your team will set specific properties of Customers while they are creating an Employee instance :) Derived classes avoid that kind of things.